# Can I create a variable in discord.py which will be individual for any user?

Tags: python, discord.py

I have a list of cards, and two users should choose their own set of cards. I use buttons so I need to throw list of selected cards from 1 view to another(I use **init** function). But discord thinks cards should be same for all users. Also, I guess this problem occurs when I throw this list between different classes.

I want that list(of selected cards) to have different values(cards chosen) for different users. Is there a way to do so?

Comment: You'll have to store the cards in a dictionary indexed by a user ID somehow.

Comment: Use a dict to map a user id to a list of cards